# Finding best match by expression

Tags: performance, optimization

**Background**

Say you have an array of numbers, and you want to find the number closest to some pre-determined value.

Example, in no particular language:

```
baseValue = 6
array = [1, 3, 5, 8, 9, 11, 13]
// 5 is the value closest to 6, and is the expected return value
```

We might solve this by keeping track of the current best match like so:

```
for value in array
    diff = abs(value - baseValue)
    if (diff < currentBestMatch)
        currentBestMatch = diff

// And at this point, currentBestMatch fits its name
```

But this code is incomplete because `currentBestMatch` is not initialized when we enter the loop, so the comparison `diff < currentBestMatch` will break.

**Possible solutions**

1. Instantiate `currentBestValue` to, say, `-1` before the loop, and expand the if-condition to
   `if (diff < currentBestMatch OR currentBestMatch == -1)`
2. Instantiate `currentBestValue` to some laughably high, but arbitrary value like the maximum allowable number of that type, so that the first check will always give a better match

**Possible problems**

1. The first solution feels wrong-ish because now we have to perform the `currentBestMatch` check. Well, technically not, because the if-condition *should* trigger on the first condition in most languages. But still, it feels like an out-of-place piece of code.
2. The second solution feels wrong-ish because what if the laughably high value actually turns out to be lower than the best match? Not to mention, what are the memory costs of storing a laughably high value for this purpose? Probably not something we'd notice this once, but what if we kept programming like that?

**Question**

Is there a more sane way to solve this problem that *feels* cleaner? I know that's a sort of handwavy definition, but I think most people here will understand what I mean.

Comment: You example array is sorted, is that a precondition? Then you can find the match faster.

Comment: @VladFeinstein - Good point. But no, that is not a precondition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using hardcoded values like `-1` or `inf` use an actual value from the array. If the array is empty, you have to handle that case anyway (maybe throw an exception), therefore accessing the first entry in the array is safe.

By the way: Instead of `currentBestMatch = diff` you probably meant `currentBestMatch = value` since you wanted to *"find the number closest to some pre-determined value"* instead of *"the difference"*.

Pseudocode:

```
if array is empty
   throw exception
diff = abs(array[0] - baseValue)
currentBestMatch = array[0]
for value in array starting at the second entry
    diff = abs(value - baseValue)
    if (diff < currentBestMatch)
        currentBestMatch = value
```

There is a small code duplication in here. You could move `abs(... - ...)` to its own function. But that is just the same as using `argmin(array, x -> abs(x-baseValue))`.